# Coefficients in linear regressions

Tags: regression, interpretation, linear

Good evening,
I have a question concerning a linear regression. The first picture shows my model and the hypotheses. The second picture shows the linear regression output for H1, H2 and H3. I understand that H2 and H3 are not significant but H1 is significant. Now I want to know: Is the β vor H1:
β = - 0,29 (Model 2) or
β = -0.30 (Model 3)?
So my question is: Although H2 and H3 are not significant, do I still take the β for H1 out of Model 3? Or is Model 3 not important and I take β for H1 out of Model 2?

Thank you for your time & greeting

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you running three models?

Comment: This is a given paper. I thought it is standard to divide the different variables in different models for better understanding.

Comment: What do you mean by "taking" a $\beta$? "Taking" for what? The $\beta$ in Model 2 and 3 are very similar, so for most uses there is hardly any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model parameters from *Model 2* should be used.

When assessing the quality of competing models, the trade off is always between the number parameters added in the larger models and the additional variance in the data explained by these additional parameters.

The [$F$ statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#Regression_problems) here, when doing direct comparisons of unconstrained models,  is just a [Likelihood ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20likelihood%2Dratio,the%20ratio%20of%20their%20likelihoods.), which compares the additional performance of the larger model vs the smaller model, taking into account the additional parameters added in the larger model.  If the ratio of the models likelihood is greater than some critical threshold, the null hypothesis specified in the smaller model is rejected.

In this case, as the $F$ statistic for *Model 2* is $F_{2} = 16.60$ and the for *Model 3* we have $F_{3} = 13.35$, then *Model 2* does a better job  better job than *Model 3* in explaining the variance in the data vs  *Model 1* (the control) with two less parameters.

Comment: Hey den173, thank you for your quick answer and the explanation. From your explanation I summarize that a smaller F statistic is better (?). Why is it then that Model 2 is better than Model 3? Is R^2 more important than the F-Statistic?

Comment: Hi @Mrs.Friday,

No, a larger F statistic is better, although in this case the difference in magnitude is marginal (both models have *F-Statistics* with the same magnitude of significance (****)). 

The F statistic for Models *2* and *3* can be "interpreted" as how much better they are at parsimoniously explaining the variance in the data vs the control model (*Model 1*). Hence, *Model 2* does a better job, as unlike *Model 3*,   it adds no non significant regression parameters with almost equivalent performance.